# How to configure a database with your spring and springboot application? I am interested to know how one should answer this type of questions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, jdbc

In one of my recent Java Microservices developer interviews, I have been asked this question “How do you configure your database with your spring and/or spring-boot application? And how does the application understands that?

I answered the interviewer explaining how I used JPA to connect to the database in my spring-boot application. And I also explained how I used JDBC(all steps including Import JDBC packages, Load and register the JDBC driver, Open a connection to the database, create a statement object to perform a query, Execute the statement object and return a query resultset, Process the resultset, Close the resultset and statement objects, Close the connection) in my applications.

But, still, the interviewer was not okay with my answers and kept on asking the same question. (I remember somewhere in between interviewer asked me about JDBC template and JDBC methods I used in spring/spring-boot)

Could anyone please help me understand what am I missing here? I am going crazy from the interview.

I am worried that how one should answer such type of interview questions?

Comment: It's really impossible to answer your question; any answer would only be guessing what the interviewer meant exactly. Next time, ask the interviewer for clarification if (s)he indicates to be not satisfied with your answer.

Comment: I agree. As I mentioned interviewer asked me whether I know jdbcTemplate and jdbc methods. Even from that I did not understand what he was actually expecting frim my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no specific answer for the question, I would assume interviewer might be looking for an answer like, how to configure dataSource or multiple datasources in springboot. Take a look [here](https://springframework.guru/how-to-configure-multiple-data-sources-in-a-spring-boot-application/)
and how can you make queries from code using diff templates assuming if you are using Spring JDBC

Comment: I am worried that how one should answer such type of interview questions? 
But sure @mahe will look into that link. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if people still using jdbc boiler plate code with spring boot. With spring boot, most people use spring data jdbc or spring data JPA, which have jdbc template and jparepository respectively. My personal preference also to avoid such boiler plate code.

Comment: I agree. I used spring data jpa, which I did explained to the interviewer but anyways he was not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

The question posed by the interviewer is pretty vague, and a lot depends on the requirements of the project, what practice is already in use, to not adopt a level of effort to migrate to a different workflow.  I've generally always worked worked with scalable micro services, and we use Spring Data to maintain a separate repository layer in our dockerized SpringBoot services.

There's a million ways to skin a cat, but without going to deep into detail, I've worked with services that are arranged like so:

A class annotated @Configuration class maintains a @Bean as your main point of access to the database.

Usually a @Service layer will pass params, with no knowledge of the query, underlying workings of the DB to a repository Interface class marked as @Repository.

The repository interface implementation class marked @Repository as well, and if needed @Scoped and @CacheConfig.
This Implementation is the meat and potatoes which executes the needed queries/transactions, with only the pertinent modifiers/terms being passed in.
Implementation executes, and returns an object back to service layer, none the wise what the service layer does, and vice versa.  Makes for smaller more maintainable classes, and you'll find if the project is large enough, that the layers can probably be refactored and generified even more, for re-use. This template can be used across all the micro services, as possibly an internal lib.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation . But, could you let me know whether my answers are correct?

Comment: As others have mentioned, there's probably no correct answer.  My guess was they were trying to get an insight into your familiarity with the Spring frameworks, how you organize your thoughts and communicate with others.

Comment: Understood. Thank you